# How to add flash animation into a video/movie file?

Tags: flash, animation, video

Hi I wonder if you can add a flash animation into a video to create some effects or animation on it without importing the video to Adobe Flash.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.hypergurl.com/blog/flash/movie-animation.html) wherein the movie is imported to Adobe Flash and then you do your animations there.

Is there any way to add the animation over a video/movie? like converting the .swf to a movie file and then merging over the two?

If there are softwares that supports the process, please suggest.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Video makers who like to use Adobe tools generally use Adobe After Effects for layering animation (and other things) on top of video. You can import both Flash animations *and* your video into After Effects and work from there.

After Effects, itself, is a decent animator for certain types of 2-D animation.  It's also a deep program that takes time to master, but, like Flash, has a lot of good online guidance available.